# Map Dimension in Various tables

Tags: ssas

I've got 3 fact tables each having a dimension called Category. Lets say Fact1-Category1, Fact2-Category2 and Fact3-Category3. Now Category1 and Category2 may have some common values, category1 and category3 have some common values and so on. Now I want to map all the categories with all the fact tables. For example if value "Homer" exist for cat1, cat2 and cat3, so whenever I select any of the 3 categories as filter Fact values should appear accordingly. I'm trying to implement reference relationship here, but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would collapse the 3 dimensions into a common "Category" dimension, and relate it to each Fact.